# Redis authentication when using Redis Sentinel failover

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I configured Redis and Redis-Sentinel in order to enable automatic failover.
Redis has one master and 2 slaves.
There are 3 sentinel nodes.

I configured redis with authentication, so in redis.conf file of the master I added this:

```
requirepass mypassword
```

and in the redis.conf of the slaves, this:

```
masterauth mypassword
```

When I stop the master, one of the slaves becomes the master, as expected.
However, when I connect to the new master using redis-cli I notice that no password is required.
I expect this is because the redis.conf file of the new master remains with the value of 'masterauth mypassword', instead of 'requirepass mypassword'.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't Redis-Sentinel configure this? or should I set something else in the conf files for the new master to require authentication?

Answer (score 2):

You should also configure slave node with password, i.e. *requirepass mypassword*.

Slave node sync data from master node, but it does not sync password. So you need to configure it manually.